# deeplink to slack from my app not opening slack

Tags: android, deep-linking, slack

In my app, I have a button that deeplinks the user to a channel in my Slack team.
However, instead of opening the Slack app and sending the user there, it actually opens another activity in my app.
If the user wants to go back to the previous activity, they need to press the back button, which confuses a lot of people.

Code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("slack://channel?team=myteam&id=mychannelid");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Is there something, like an intent flag, I might be missing?

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough. What is the relation between the slack app and yours?

Comment: If intent launch a new Activity on your app, maybe you have declare a <intent-filter> in your manifest file for ACTION_VIEW. Can you provide your manifest file ?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `<intent-filter>` in your android manifest that has an action like

`<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />.`

Comment: the only intent filter in my manifest is <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> for my main activity